# how to display an auto increment value in a textbox using session

Tags: php

> Login.php

```
     session_start();
     <?php

     $username = "root";
     $password = "tiger";
     $hostname = "localhost"; 
     //connection to the database
      $dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
     or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

     //select a database to work with
     /* @var $selected type */
     $selected = mysqli_select_db($dbhandle,"sample") 
     or die("Could not select sample");
     $name=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'name'));
     $phone=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'phone'));
     $email=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'email'));
     //$custno=(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'custno'));
     if(!empty(\filter_input(\INPUT_POST,'continue')))
       {
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
         'check()';
         echo "</script>";
           $sql="insert into customersignin(name,phone,email)values('$name','$phone','$email')";
         $result=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql) or die(\mysqli_error($dbhandle));


}
  else
   {
   $sql1="insert into customersignin(custno)values(NULL)";
    $result1=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql1) or die(\mysqli_error($dbhandle)); 

 }
 $sql2="select custno from customersignin";
 $result2=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql2) or die (mysqli_error($dbhandle));
  $row=  mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result2)>0)
  {

   echo  "$_SESSION['custno']";
   unset($_SESSION['custno'];
    header('Location:customersvsoup.php');
  }

mysqli_close($dbhandle);

$_SESSION[name]=(\filter_input(INPUT_POST,'name'));
```

> customer.php

```
   <body>
   <?php session_start(); ?>
   <input type="text" style="position: absolute;top:200px;" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["custno"]?>">
</body>
```

> In the php file the customer log in is done,the custno is the auto generate field,i have 2 buttons called continue and skip,for both the auto generate works fine,after any of the button action is done,i need to display the custno in the text box of the next page using session.But the problem is the text box is empty when i run this code.But the session['name'] is working..Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `session_start();` should come at the beginning of the file in `login.php`. I see you using `$_SESSION[custno]` before it's called. That's why your textbox is empty.

Also it should be:

`$_SESSION['custno']` 
`$_SESSION['name']`*note the single quotes*

Regarding your logical problem (in the comments) try:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name'));

if (!empty(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'continue')))
    {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
    'check()';
    echo "</script>";
    $sql = "insert into customersignin(name,phone,email)values('$name','$phone','$email')";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbhandle, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));
    $sql2 = "select max(custno) as last_custno from customersignin";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($dbhandle, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0)
        {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
        $_SESSION['custno'] = $row['last_custno'];
        header('Location:customersvsoup.php');
        }
    }
  else
    {
    $sql1 = "insert into customersignin(custno)values(NULL)";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($dbhandle, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));
    //since this bit of code is repeating,
    //you could even use a function to shorten it
    $sql2 = "select max(custno) as last_custno from customersignin";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($dbhandle, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0)
        {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
        $_SESSION['custno'] = $row['last_custno'];
        header('Location:customersvsoup.php');
        }
    }
```

And please put the `session_start();` **inside** after `<?php`. All php code should be within the PHP tags.

Comment: before $_SESSION[custno] i have given the session_start()

Comment: Not sure if it's useful to have `session_start()` twice. Anyways, place the single quote inside your session variable.

Comment: yes i have placed,still no changes. im amble to display the name but not the custno

Comment: You placed the session start at the beginning of the PHP file?

Comment: @user3516005 Actually looking at your code, your second sql query will never get executed because you are redirecting in the first `if` `elseif`

Comment: oh k..so how can i change?

Comment: @user3516005 Your updated code is confusing. Can you be clear about what value you want to store in `$_SESSION['cust_no']` and under which condition?

Comment: plese check the edits..it is an auto increment value whenever the login is done,the value is autoincremented in the mysql database whenever the continue and skip button is clicked

Comment: @user3516005 I can vaguely understand what you are trying to achieve, check the above edited code.

Comment: @user3516005 If this answer is correct, please tick the check mark at the left so that this question remains solved.

Answer (score 0):

you have error in insert query:

```
$sql="insertintocustomersignin(name,phone,email)values('$name','$phone','$email')";
```

should be :

```
$sql="insert into customersignin(name,phone,email) values ('$name','$phone','$email')";
```

you should use quotes in array index :
`$_SESSION[custno], $_SESSION[name]` should be `$_SESSION['custno'], $_SESSION['name']`

Comment: can you make sure that `$_SESSION[custno]=(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'custno'));` is executed ? just `echo $_SESSION[custno] ; ` and die

Comment: did it echo the value `$_SESSION[custno]` ?

Comment: after i click continue it redirects to the customer.php page,im not able to see where it echoes or whetherit does

Comment: put php `die();` after echoing